# compose a page from different resources scala template In play! 2.0

Tags: templates, playframework, playframework-2.0

If I have A main page which composed from more than one section (header,main,side,etc..),each Is loaded from different URL say header Is composed from /head side section Is loaded from /side we used to use `Include` in other frameworks.how can I do this In play! 2.0
I used Jquery to do It but can't this be done natively

```
$.get("/hello", function(result){
      $("#xxx").html(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by Marcus, this is detailed in [official documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaTemplateUseCases).

In fact, you do not paste together results from different URL. You define in your template which templates have to be used.

You can include other templates using :

```
<h1>Home</h1>

<div id="side">
  @common.sideBar()
</div>
```

But if you plan to have a global frame surrounding your pages, you should have a look to `extended template` :

```
@otherTemplate("Title"){

   //Html content here ...

}
```

**Update** :

if what you are trying to do is retrieve an absolute URL from a controller, you have to use the [reverse routing](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaRouting):

```
@routes.Application.hello("Bob").absoluteUrl()
```

Comment: I knew about this, what I'm looking for Is Including other content from different URI

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you are trying to do. I have updated my answer to describe reverse routing (retrieve an absolute URL to a controller using the routes pattern)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="side">
  @common.sideBar()
</div>
```

BTW it's from [official documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaTemplateUseCases).